# Failed to build web application after changing my org.springframework.social.version version

Tags: spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am using org.springframework.social for facebook login in my web application. I have updated my version to.

```
<org.springframework.social.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.social.version>
```

And now I am not able to build my application. The dependencies are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.social.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.social.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.social.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.social.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.social.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Social Twitter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.social.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And the error I am getting now is

```
Failed to execute goal on project my-web-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com:my-web-project:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE, org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE, org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE, org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE, org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.0.2: Could not find artifact org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

any help for this?

Comment: There is no 2.0.1 version of Spring Social, only for the Spring Social Facebook component.

Comment: Thanks for the help. now build is done.